# How to implement simple login page in Django?

Tags: python, django

Basically, I've made the login page which is called html. I'll explain the problem.

The site I have has the current tabs: Home, profile, leaderboard and members.

However, for the members tab is for the admin to add and edit the members details. Currently, anyone can edit it and thats not really realistic - it should only be for the admin. After the leaderboard tab I've made an Admin tab which has the login page, but when I click on "login" after entering the username and password, it doesnt do anything (because I don't know how to).

When the the admin has entered their details they should be directed to the Members page which I have already created.

Basically, how do I redirect the admin to the member after login. The login button doesnt do anything atm. I'll show you what I have..

**Leaderboard.html (page before Admin)**

```
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Members Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'leaderboard' %}">Leaderboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'admin' %}">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'all_members' %}">Members</a></li>
```

**Login.html**

```
<form action='' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
    <div >
        <label for='username'> Username </label>
        <input type='text' name='Username' id='username'>
        <label for='password'>Password </label>
        <input type='password' name='Password' id='password'>
        <input type='submit' value='login'>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Views.py**

```
def login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response("templates/login.html", context)    


def all_members(request): <-- Login should go to this view. 
    return render(request, 'templates/members.html', 
{'members': Member.objects.all()})
```

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'leaderboard', views.leaderboard, name='leaderboard'),
url(r'login', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^(?P<member_id>\d+)/$', views.edit_member, name='edit_member'),
url(r'^add/$', views.add_member, name='add_member'),
url(r'members', views.all_members, name='all_members'),
```

Comment: Have you read the [very comprehensive documentation on authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/)?

Comment: Authentication is not necessary for my example

Comment: Er, what? How can you have login without authentication?

Comment: I get what you mean, but for this piece of work, its not required. Admin for username and password is fine.

Comment: Will any username and password do?

Comment: Well, now I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea what you are asking about. if you don't want to authenticate the user, what's your problem?

Comment: Okay..basically: when I click on the login button, it should go to the members page that i've made. Thats all!

Comment: If only serveral usernames and passwords combinations can be allowed, that's for me an authentication definition...

Comment: What's the point of having a login form if you're not going to even look at the username or password??? Why not have just a login link?

Comment: @OozeMeister Tell that to my university haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will not check the validity of username and password, just write your login view as:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect('all_members')
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response("templates/login.html", context)
```

Still, this is a very weird use case but it should work for your scenario.

Comment: Noo..it's a piece of work for university. Nothing to worry about!